# Windows Server 2008 R2 Software Raid 5, Resynching (4 days so far)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, software-raid, raid5

I have a software raid 5 of 5x1,5Tb harddrives, this raid has been made in Windows Server 2008 R2.
Now I know that Resynching can take a lot of time to be preformed, but so far have it been running for 4 days and it is only 5x1,5TB harddrives, so I am starting to wonder what is happening! Is there any way I can see how far along it is in the process, as it only says "Resynching"?

Edit: Now is Saturday 3/4-2011 and it is still Resynching, and it have not been powered down since then.

Comment: How long was your raid set healthy before it started resynching?

Comment: whats the server spec ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/277530/how-can-i-view-server-2008-software-raid-5-resync-progress
Try checking from a rdp connection as described here.

Answer (score 5):

The percentage of resync complete doesn't show initially.  Load up disk manager, and press F5 (or click refresh).  This then seems to cause the percentage complete to show.

My 3 x 3tb RAID5 has been running for about 20 hours and has done 23%

Comment: These extremely long rebuild times (during which the entire array is degraded and subject to failure) are one of the main reasons why RAID5 is not recommended for terabyte-scale drives.

Answer (score 1):

Try the steps described in this link: [How to view status of software RAID 1 resynching?](https://serverfault.com/questions/107636/how-to-view-status-of-software-raid-1-resynching/119586#119586)

I'm not *certain* that Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 are identical in this respect, but I'm suspecting that they are.

Comment: i did try them, but sadly dose it not apply to windows server 2008