# How can I view Server 2008 Software RAID 5 Resync Progress?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, software-raid, raid5

Skipping over the pros/cons of RAID 5, I have a software RAID-5 array made from 3x 2TB disks. I started the sync and nearly 12 hours later the sync is still going. Is there any way that I can view the progress of the sync? Most screenshots I've seen of a RAID setup shows "Resyncing [x]%" but not on mine.

F5 in disk manager does nothing.

Going to More Tasks > Refresh also shows nothing.

File Services installed, nothing extra.

CPU (Dual Core 2.0GHz) is between 1-5% usage, RAM is between 500-550MB (of 2GB).
[image]

Comment: The rebuild can take a lot longer than 12 hours. Have you tried to load the disk management mmc from another computer and connect to the rebuilding server? I have had odd behavior on occasion from 2k8 disk management. Sometimes connecting from a remote computer works.

Comment: Not yet, I will try that once I get home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it looks like there's no "for sure" way. When I RDP into the server it, more often than not, shows the progress in Disk Management.

I have found an answer on [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/119586/41103) here which says either press "F5" and refresh the console that way, or go into the right-hand "Actions" menu, choose "more actions" and "refresh" with **resynchronising RAID volume** selected and that seems to do the trick as well.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but after finding it during my investigation of an answer, I found an article [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26241507/Window-Software-Raid-resync-status.html) which has [this comment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26241507/Window-Software-Raid-resync-status.html#a35266490) which turned out to be a solution for me in server 2012 R2, even though it is on a question regarding server 2003.

To summarise the comment; in the Disk Management GUI you will only get a percentage figure next to the disks during a resync once each launch of the Disk Management interface and only after you perform a refresh (using F5 for example) after having loaded Disk Management.

Further refreshes will lose the percentage value - you need to close and repeat the process to obtain current progress.

NB: the resync in my case was the first ever, as I had only just created the RAID-5 volume, I am doing this on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard - but this method is working for me while I monitor the operation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is to wait!

Leave the disks alone, don't write any new data to them.  I had `resynching' as a progress for days whilst restoring from backup, but then something went awry - rebuilt the array and left it alone, after a few hours saw the magical "3%" status.

Patience, is after all, a virtue...